# How to integrate ECS with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

Can anyone please help me with step by step procedure to integrate elastic container service with Jenkins as I am really new to this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually we just launched an Jenkins in an instance, and what to use ECS to for containers to deploy our project.